# Unable to call .click function - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, add-on

I'm creating a Firefox/Chrome Addon that goes on a 3rd party website. On this site, there is a list of about 512 names in one `ul`. I want to put 12 of them, based on their values and compared to an array.

Each `li` item looks like so:

```
<li><a class="manip" href="javascript:void(0);"></a><span class="draggable in-MultiCheckPossibleUserIdslistpair-possible ui-draggable"><a class="user" href="javascript:jQuery.wp.showModalWindow('/OneProof/User/Info/31654022')">Aaron Quinby</a><span class="id">31654022</span><span class="sortNo">1</span></span><span class="preview" style="display: none;">Aaron Quinby</span></li>
```

Right now, clicking on the a tag, with `manip` class will bring the `li` item from one `ul` to the correct `ul`. I want to do this automatically with my addon. I figured the quickest way would be to call the .click() event with jQuery on the a tag like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".manip").each(function() {
    //quick check to see if it works, click all
    $(this).click();
});
});
```

I've played with the click, calling it in the console, calling it after a delay, and few other ways.

The only JavaScript I can find associated with the `manip` class in the source for this site is the following:

```
universe.find("a.manip")
        .click(function() {
            //alert("bound");
            $.dropIt($(this).parent(), false);
        });
```

Is there a reason why the .click call event isn't working?

Thanks!

Edit: Universe is defined here:

```
function listpairCore(options) {
    var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.listPair.options, options);
    var thisId = this.attr("id");
    var ulSelected = this.find("ul.selected");
    var ulPossible = this.find("ul.possible");
    var universe = this;
```

and listpaircore is called here

```
$.fn.listPair = listpairCore;
```

Comment: Are you able to show the declaration of `universe`?

Comment: @JohnC Oooh, you might be onto something. updated

Comment: I updated my answer if you're still stuck on this.

Answer (score 1):

The click function does not simulate a click. It binds an event handler to the click event.

What you want is

```
$(this).trigger( "click" );
```

**Update:**

The javascript you found in the source references the "manip" class as

```
universe.find("a.manip")
```

so maybe try doing the same?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    universe.find("a.manip").each(function() {
        //quick check to see if it works, click all
        $(this).trigger("click");
    });
});
```

Comment: Just gave that a shot, still didn't work. Thanks though

Comment: @AngryMarker I don't think we're seeing enough of your code here.  And I suspect in the time it takes you to put together a Fiddle, you will solve your problem.  Still, you should try.